# How to do a timed activity in a for loop Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked everywhere and haven't found any answer that satisfy my needs, I need some way so that when I press the button start each cell of the collection gets painted black.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!

    @IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        for item in 0...24 {
            var place = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "paintCell:", userInfo: "place", repeats: false)

        }

    }

    func paintCell (cell: NSIndexPath) {

        collection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(cell)?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 25
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        return cell

}

    var timer = NSTimer()

}
```

Comment: What is not working at the moment?

Comment: The app crashes when I press start and the error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException appears on the console

Comment: your selector is wrong for the timer method. You should put place in the userInfo argument and use "paintCell:" as selector. It is better to read the method document for more details.

Comment: 24 separate timers are unnecessary too. Start a single timer and then loop through your cells once the timer fires

Comment: @zp_x Still not working, please check the edit

Comment: Why do you want to create 25 timers to turn of the cells? One loop is enough. Are you trying to turn the cells off 1 second after another?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK - the first problem is that you have defined the selector as `paintCell`, but you don't have a function that matches that - you have `paintCell(cell: NSIndexPath)` - that's why you're getting unrecognised selector

That said - it's still not the best way to go about this.  You don't need 25 different timers for this.  If your code was working, then all 25 timers would fire at the same time, and update the images.  If that's what you actually want, you only need one timer, fired once.  If you actually want them to change once per second until all are done, then here's a different approach, using a single timer, and a variable for the index.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var collection: UICollectionView!

    var indexCollection = 0
    var timer = NSTimer()

    @IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        // start the timer running, and reset the index
        indexCollection = 0
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "paintCell", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func paintCell()
    {
        print(indexCollection)  // just for demonstration.  You don't need this

        // access the cell through the indexCollection
        collection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: indexCollection, inSection: 0))?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        if indexCollection < 24
        {
            indexCollection++
        }
        else
        {
            // everything is finished, so stop the timer
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see the numbers being printed, but the cells don't actually update their color.

Comment: that sounds like a new question!  If you're happy that the timer question you asked has been resolved, then accept this answer, and raise a new one about updating the color

Answer (score 0):

The signaturefor you `paintCell` is wrong. The target invocation of an `NSTimer` should take an `NSTimer` as its only input argument:

```
@IBAction func startButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    for i in 0..<25 {
        let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0))
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("paintCell:"), userInfo: cell, repeats: false)
    }
}

func paintCell(timer: NSTimer) {
    if let cell = timer.userInfo as? UICollectionViewCell {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    timer.invalidate()
}
```

But why ask for 25 timers just to turn 25 cells to black? These timers will fire at exactly the same time. Much more efficient if you just use a `for` loop instead:

```
for i in 0..<25 {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
    let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}
```

Nice and easy to read for everyone!

---

On the other hand, if you want to turn each cell to black *1 second after another*, use `dispatch_after`:

```
@IBAction func startButton2(sender: AnyObject) {
    paintCell2(0)
}

func paintCell2(index: Int) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
    let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    if index < 25 {
        let delay = Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay)
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.paintCell2(index + 1)
        }
    }
}
```